# How to export default your component without component name?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

How can I export default my component without exporting with a name and use `withRouter` in it? This `ProtectedRoute` is just a collection for props to display component.

```
export default () => (
  <ProtectedRoute
    path="/home"
    component={MyComponent}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap your component with withRouter while exporting like

```
export default withRouter(() => (
  <ProtectedRoute
    path="/home"
    component={MyComponent}
  />
));
```